# trouble reindexing python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reindex

I have a simple dictionary I deleted an index entry in the middle. I'm having trouble re-ordering `my_dict` index keys to be in sequence after I deleted an entry in the middle.

```
my_dict = {
    0: {
        "item_one": "a",
        "item_two": "b",

    },
    1: {
        "item_one": "c",
        "item_two": "d",

    },
    2: {
        "item_one": "e",
        "item_two": "f",

    }
}

del my_dict[1]

my_dict = {
    0: {
        "item_one": "a",
        "item_two": "b",

    },
    2: {
        "item_one": "e",
        "item_two": "f",
    }
}
```

I'm trying to loop through `my_dict` to change the keys to be in sequence from `(0, 1, ...)` instead of `(0, 2, ...)`.

I was using the `.keys(`) method to loop through my_dict and try and changes keys to reorder the dictionary keys to be in sequence but having trouble.

Comment: A list would probably be more appropriate to use than a dict for this?

Comment: Dicts are not ordered lists by definition.  You are using the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) instead of [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), as *Iain Shelvington* suggested in the comment. This is the correct data structure when you need to iterate by an integer, consecutive index. You can slice and dice it using `del`, `pop`, [list slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/967621) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
my_dict = {
    "0": {
        "item_one": "a",
        "item_two": "b",  
    },
    "1": {
        "item_one": "c",
        "item_two": "d",
    },
    "2": {
        "item_one": "e",
        "item_two": "f",
    }
}

lst = list(my_dict.values())
print(lst)
# [{'item_one': 'a', 'item_two': 'b'}, {'item_one': 'c', 'item_two': 'd'}, {'item_one': 'e', 'item_two': 'f'}]

# To delete a list element:

# use del:
del lst[1]
# or pop:
lst.pop(1)
# or list slices:
lst = lst[:1] + lst[2:]

# In any of the cases above:
print(lst)
# [{'item_one': 'a', 'item_two': 'b'}, {'item_one': 'e', 'item_two': 'f'}]
```

Comment: thxs! a bit more context, I'm taking user input from a tkinter listbox and saving it to a .json file for reuse when running the program again.  I was trying to build a function that removes selected users inputs from the listbox if they choose.  I was having trouble with structuring the data in a list and was using this nested dictionary instead but will give it another try.  I'm still pretty new to python, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `enumerate()` to create new keys for the dictionary.

```
my_dict = dict(enumerate(my_dict.values()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Yet another approach

```
my_odict = dict(
    sorted(
        my_dict.items(),
        key=lambda item: int(item[0])
    )
)
```

Comment: Keeps the same keys, doesn't change 2 to 1.

Comment: Indeed, wasn't interpreting the OP's question this way... So clearly there is no reason not to go with lists instead.